# Display issue with certain values in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am having a problem:

```
<% @post.each do |post| %>
    <%=link_to post.title, post %>
    <p>Published
    <%= time_ago_in_words(post.created_at) %> ago by
    <%= post.user.user_name %></p>
<% end %>
```

The user name doesn't display it stays just blank in the webpage while if i type:

```
<%= post.user.email%>
```

It works the email displays. I don't understand why the `user_name` isn't showing up and for me it makes no sense. I am using the weBrick server for development if you need to now.

Comment: `user_name` field may not contains value

Comment: It does contain though

Comment: When you sign up you fill the user_name field and the user_name is stored in the database

Comment: can you post output of `<%= post.user.inspect %>` here

Comment: sauickbsakjhxoi
Published 32 minutes ago by #<User id: 2, user_name: nil, full_name: nil, email: "redbaronchannel1@gmail.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$dZ/7Yg/MB06vQcyFnzCKNucub78cZvK3vEsyw/Z4l3d...", role: nil, created_at: "2015-12-25 09:55:17", updated_at: "2015-12-25 09:55:17">

This hso,jsdkud
Published 35 minutes ago by #<User id: 1, user_name: nil, full_name: nil, email: "mateo@email.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$wLxvI3RYjjIY2lmga0irU.Rlf0pwCM6/HlsgbI10eb1...", role: nil, created_at: "2015-12-25 09:39:37", updated_at: "2015-12-25 09:39:37">

Comment: user_name is nil, as you can see.

Comment: @Hansi : it clearly shows `user_name: nil`

Comment: I don't understand why they are nil and also in my rails app a new seperate folder has popped named .idea

Comment: I know but how can i fix it

Comment: There's nothing to fix. User name doesn't show because there is no username. Set some value to the username and it'll show

Comment: have you added `:user_name, :full_name` in your strong parameter? I guess you haven't

Comment: It apperd that in the user controller i had write that in a private parameter not :user_name but full_name i think that that will fix it .

Comment: Thanks to anyone who came to help

Comment: @HansiCollaku : Update your post with User controller's code. without check your code no one can help you.

Answer (score 1):

It probably means you don't have `user_name` present in the associative user field, although if it was missing completely, it would normally throw an exception.

I'd say the record is *blank* or *NULL* in the db, hence it has no actual value when you output it.

The way to resolve is to make sure you're storing the value in your db. Rails has [`validations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#presence) for this purpose:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   validates :user_name, presence: true
end
```

This will fire each time you `create` or `update` a user record, which means that when you send params like in your comments...

```
#<User id: 1, user_name: nil, full_name: nil, email: "mateo@email.com", password_digest: "$2a$10$wLxvI3RYjjIY2lmga0irU.Rlf0pwCM6/HlsgbI10eb1...", role: nil, created_at: "2015-12-25 09:39:37", updated_at: "2015-12-25 09:39:37">
```

... it will come back with an error that you cannot create the record because `user_name` is not present.

---

In situations like this, we use a method to fall back onto the email if the `name` doesn't exist:

```
#app/models/user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
   def user_name
       self[:user_name] || email
   end
end
```

This allows you to call `@user.name` and if they don't have it, it pulls the `email` instead.

This way, if you validate on having the email present, you'll be able to always return a value.

--

Another cool trick is [`delegate`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Module.html#method-i-delegate), which avoids the [`law of demeter`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter) (IE only have one point when calling attributes):

```
#app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
   delegate :user_name, to: :user
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
<%= post.user_name %>
```

... with it calling the `user_name` attribute from the `User` model.